# Multiple SearchBar in NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm new in developing applications on iOS and I'm trying to add into NavigationBar 2 SearchBar. One SearchBar is simple to add with:

```
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
```

but I don't know how can add 2 searchbar in navigationbar.

I would like to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to add multiple search bars in Navigation Bar. The best solution that I can suggest you according to your designs given above is to add two UITextFields or two UISearchBars in your ViewController and not in your Navigation Bar.